# Countif : Trying to count multiple values from a filtered column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count values in a column which is filtered by values in another column. Got it to work using the countifs however I want to count 2 value sets in the filtered column can't seem to get it to count both. So below is the currently working formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(June!K2:K1000,"username",June!I2:I1000,"=cancelled")
```

What I want to do is

```
=COUNTIFS(June!K2:K1000,"username",June!I2:I1000,"=cancelled"+"=no show")
```

But cant seem to get it to function. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So it's all instances of username in Column K, which have either cancelled OR no show in Column I? or is it AND cancelled / no show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COUNTIFS(June!K2:K1000,"username",June!I2:I1000,"=cancelled")+COUNTIFS(June!K2:K1000,"username",June!I2:I1000,"=no show")
```

This should work for you if i understand what you want this formula to do

Answer (score 0):

You can get `"OR"` behaviour without repeating the `COUNTIFS` function by using this syntax:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(June!K2:K1000,"username",June!I2:I1000,{"cancelled","no show"}))`

The `COUNTIFS` function returns a two value "array" (one each for `cancelled` and `no show`), so you need the `SUM` function to sum both counts to give your total

This should give the same result as poof's suggestion with 2 `COUNTIFS`